# Identify a Sci Fi cartoon where they had space suits and would fight in outer space

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

I need help remembering the name of a cartoon I used to watch. 
It was shown on weekday mornings in Australia in the mid 90's. They had space suits and they would fight in outerspace. The characters were human but were also alien. The villain was on the dark side of the moon. The main character was susceptible  to become a villain  if he used too much of his energy and would lose control.

Comment: Can you remember any details about the individual characters? The villain?

Comment: Was this an anime? Or Western animation?

Comment: Did it have something to do with crystals or insect aliens? Sounds partly like Technoman Blade.

Comment: @cde -Agreed. Mention of the "dark side of the moon" and characters that are human/alien would fit nicely; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekkaman_Blade

Comment: @CDE: Would you like to come back and post that as an answer?

Comment: @cde - OP has confirmed that this is indeed Technoman Blade. You need to post your comment as an answer so you can get the rep.

Comment: YES! Been searching for this all night, couldn't remember the name of it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did it have something to do with crystals or insect aliens? Sounds partly like [Tekkaman Blade.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekkaman_Blade) It involved an alien invasion by insectoid creatures, which the titular character fought. He gained his powers from the alien invader's power crystal, which was supposed to brainwash him, but because it was cracked did not. **Instead he has a limited amount of time that he can transform until it takes him over.**

[image]

Comment: Oh, c'mon - you can do better than that. Flesh that sucker out, add a picture and some pretty formatting. ;P

Comment: @omega when I'm not mobile