# Anime where people with the help of some sort of crystal able to get bionic suits

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime

I cannot recall the name of this anime. It's about people who can, with the help of some sort of crystal, get these bionic suits in which they fight against aliens with like yellow blood, and a group of three who want to extract the core from these aliens. The bionic suits of these three are also yellow.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Details like where you saw this anime, and when would be very helpful. Also, any additional plot details, and a more descriptive title would be appreciated.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81930/identify-a-sci-fi-cartoon-where-they-had-space-suits-and-would-fight-in-outer-sp?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135525/what-anime-features-a-boy-with-a-gem-or-crystal-that-gives-him-powers-to-transfo

Comment: I also am searching for the same anime. But can't find it. It basically features a boy with a handicapped sister both having some mutations that gave them power to use these crystals extracted from these aliens. The aliens can only be defeated by shattering their head shields and then breaking the crystal releasing yellow blood. The school where he study, most girls want to be with him. kind of a pervy type.
In one episode, her sister also uses crystal powers to sing in a concert alongside a singing star who also uses crystal power in concert.

Answer (score 2):

Is it *The Guyver*?  I'm not particularly familiar with the story, but it does involve a crystal that gives you some kind of armor and powers.  The bad guy aliens if memory serves were after the Guyver in order to get its crystal.

Comment: Could you add some frames from the anime?

Comment: I am horrible when it comes to manipulating data like that but I can list a basic link to youtube :) Maybe the video in the link will jog the questioners memory for more info if my answer turns out to be wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjCyyoTLYMA&list=PLTtO437w3ypZPf9FsPDSyRA-KS2dC9jtl

Answer (score 2):

I got it - its name is [*Hundred*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31338/Hundred).

[image: Poster]

> When an extraterrestrial organism known as "Savage" attacks mankind, the only technology capable of combating the enemy is a weapon known as “Hundred.” A survivor of a Savage attack, Hayato Kisaragi is a teenager boasting the highest compatibility level with the aforementioned technology and as a result, is invited to master his skills at Little Garden, a prestigious military academy aboard a battleship.
>
> Over the course of his intense training for the battle ahead, he immediately attracts the interest of multiple female peers and gets drawn into a number of incidents as he tries to fight against the creatures that now inhabit Earth and threaten its safety.  <sub>- Synopsis from MyAnimeList</sub>

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the question. Could you explain why you believe this is the correct answer?